# Android/Java - CountDown Timer not working

Tags: java, android, time, countdown, countdowntimer

I am making a timer as part of my app. I followed a tutorial, and made some modifications to the program to better suit my needs. However, when I run the app, I get the default value of the timerTextView (defined in xml), or just random numbers. What is going wrong?

**Update**: Here is the coomplete code for the activity:

```
public class Main7Activity extends AppCompatActivity {




private TextView countDownText;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
//private long timeLeftInMilliseconds = 1000*60*60*24*7*1;
public TextView textView3;
public TextView textView4;
public TextView textView5;
public TextView textView6;


public long timeLeftInMilliseconds;

//private int daysToGo;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main7);




    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testText);
    textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testText2);
    textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testText3);
    textView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testText4);






    //textView3.setText(Integer.toString(Main6Activity.progress2));


    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();


    textView3.setText("LMP date : " + Main6Activity.textView.getText());

    int currentDayOfYear = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);



    //Day of year is the LMP date
    now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Main6Activity.progress2);
    int lmpDate = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);


    //Day of year is due date
    now.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7*40);


    textView4.setText("Due Date: " + now.get(Calendar.DATE) + "-"
            + (now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + now.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    int dueDate = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    if (dueDate < 365 && lmpDate > 82){
        dueDate = dueDate + (365);
    }

    if (lmpDate<82 && lmpDate>49){
        dueDate = dueDate + lmpDate;
    }



    if (lmpDate<50) {
        textView5.setText("Congratulations on Delivery");
    }

    else {

        textView5.setText(Integer.toString(dueDate));
    }
    //textView5.setText(now.getTime().toString());
    //int currentDayOfYear  = Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR;

    int daysToGo = dueDate - currentDayOfYear;
    textView6.setText(Integer.toString(daysToGo));





    timeLeftInMilliseconds = 1000*60*60*24*daysToGo;


    countDownText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weeks);
    startTimer();

}



public void startTimer(){
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMilliseconds, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeLeftInMilliseconds = millisUntilFinished;
            updateTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}


public void updateTimer(){
    int weeks = (int) timeLeftInMilliseconds / 604800000;
    int days = (int) (timeLeftInMilliseconds % 604800000) / 86400000;
    //int hours = (int) (timeLeftInMilliseconds % 86400000) / 3600000;
    //int minutes = (int) (timeLeftInMilliseconds % 3600000) / 60000;
    int seconds = (int) (timeLeftInMilliseconds % 60000) / 1000;

    String timeLeftText;

    timeLeftText = "";
    if (weeks < 10) timeLeftText += "0";
    timeLeftText += weeks;
    timeLeftText += ":";
    if (days < 10) timeLeftText += "0";
    timeLeftText += days;
    //timeLeftText += ":";
    //if (hours < 10) timeLeftText += "0";
    //timeLeftText += hours;
    //timeLeftText += ":";
    //timeLeftText += minutes;
    //timeLeftText += ":";
    if (seconds < 10) timeLeftText += "0";
    timeLeftText += seconds;

    countDownText.setText(timeLeftText);
}



public void editInfo(View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent(Main7Activity.this, Main6Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

I also need the timer to run in the background. Will this code do that?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post complete activity code?

Comment: Make sure your countDownText.setText(timeLeftText) runs on the main thread. I think if you try to update ui items from background threads, it wont actualy update the ui. I cant see where do you run your timer class so I am not sure if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.

Timer_Service.java

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Timer_Service extends Service {

    public static String str_receiver = "your_package_name.receiver";

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    Calendar calendar;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
    String strDate;
    Date date_current, date_diff;
    SharedPreferences mpref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

    private Timer mTimer = null;
    public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 1000;
    Intent intent;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        mEditor = mpref.edit();
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 5, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
        intent = new Intent(str_receiver);
    }


    class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                    Log.e("strDate", strDate);
                    twoDatesBetweenTime();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public String twoDatesBetweenTime() {

        try {
            date_current = simpleDateFormat.parse(strDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        try {
            date_diff = simpleDateFormat.parse(mpref.getString("data", ""));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        try {
            long diff = date_current.getTime() - date_diff.getTime();
            int int_hours = Integer.valueOf(mpref.getString("hours", ""));

            long int_timer = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(int_hours);
            long long_hours = int_timer - diff;
            long diffSeconds2 = long_hours / 1000 % 60;
            long diffMinutes2 = long_hours / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long diffHours2 = long_hours / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;


            if (long_hours > 0) {
                String str_testing = diffHours2 + ":" + diffMinutes2 + ":" + diffSeconds2;

                Log.e("TIME", str_testing);

                fn_update(str_testing);
            } else {
                mEditor.putBoolean("finish", true).commit();
                mTimer.cancel();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            mTimer.purge();
        }

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Service finish", "Finish");
    }

    private void fn_update(String str_time) {

        intent.putExtra("time", str_time);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Your Timer.java activity:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class Timer extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btn_start, btn_cancel;
    private TextView tv_timer;
    String date_time;
    Calendar calendar;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
    EditText et_hours;

    SharedPreferences mpref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        btn_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_timer);
        tv_timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_timer);
        et_hours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_hours);
        btn_cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);

        btn_start.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        mpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        mEditor = mpref.edit();

        try {
            String str_value = mpref.getString("data", "");
            if (str_value.matches("")) {
                et_hours.setEnabled(true);
                btn_start.setEnabled(true);
                tv_timer.setText("");

            } else {

                if (mpref.getBoolean("finish", false)) {
                    et_hours.setEnabled(true);
                    btn_start.setEnabled(true);
                    tv_timer.setText("");
                } else {

                    et_hours.setEnabled(false);
                    btn_start.setEnabled(false);
                    tv_timer.setText(str_value);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_timer:


                if (et_hours.getText().toString().length() > 0) {

                    int int_hours = Integer.valueOf(et_hours.getText().toString());

                    if (int_hours <= 24) {


                        et_hours.setEnabled(false);
                        btn_start.setEnabled(false);


                        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                        date_time = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

                        mEditor.putString("data", date_time).commit();
                        mEditor.putString("hours", et_hours.getText().toString()).commit();


                        Intent intent_service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Timer_Service.class);
                        startService(intent_service);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select the value below 24 hours", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
/*
                    mTimer = new Timer();
                    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 5, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);*/
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;


            case R.id.btn_cancel:


                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Timer_Service.class);
                stopService(intent);

                mEditor.clear().commit();

                et_hours.setEnabled(true);
                btn_start.setEnabled(true);
                tv_timer.setText("");

                break;
        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String str_time = intent.getStringExtra("time");
            tv_timer.setText(str_time);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Timer_Service.str_receiver));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

Your activity_timer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_hours"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:hint="Hours"
        android:inputType="time" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_timer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:text="Start Timer" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="cancel timer" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Resource reference: [this link](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2016/11/07/android-countdown-timer-run-in-background/).

You need to do some modifications according to your requirement. The countdown will continue even if you close the app.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i am not looking to make a complete timer app only. This is an activity part of my application and must execute on create of the activity automatically.

Comment: @BLRBoy what exactly you want to achieve? you want countDown Timer to run in the background till your app is running or you want it to run even if your app is closed.

Comment: the timer should run even when the app is closed. However, the code you proposed has buttons for starting and stopping. I need the code to execute automatically. The code in the original post/question has a variable called daysToGo. The countdown timer should count down to those many days from the current date. daysToGo is reduced by 1 every day. However, the code I posted does not work. I get random values or the default value of the count down textview when the code is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare those variables :

```
    Handler countHandler ;
    Runnable countRunnable ;
    private final long INTERVAL = 1000 ; // this the interval period which the timer will be triggered each time
```

Then change your method like this :

```
public void startTimer(){
        countHandler = new Handler() ;
        countRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateTimer();

                timeLeftInMilliseconds= timeLeftInMilliseconds - INTERVAL ;

                if(timeLeftInMilliseconds>=0){
                    countHandler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL) ;
                } else {
                    cancelTimer(); // here timer is finished
                }
            }
        } ;
        countHandler.post(countRunnable) ;
    }

    public void cancelTimer(){
        countHandler.removeCallbacks(countRunnable);
    }
```